# single query for update and select inner join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to combine these two queries?

select mysql query:

```
SELECT avg(b.averageRating) 
FROM review a INNER 
JOIN review b ON b.institudeId=a.institudeId 
WHERE a.reviewId='3';
```

update mysql query:

```
update table institutions 
set averageRatings=avg(b.averageRating) 
where id=a.institudeId;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
UPDATE institutions SET institutions.overallRatings = (
  SELECT avg(b.averageRating) 
  FROM review a 
  INNER JOIN review b ON b.institudeId=a.institudeId WHERE a.reviewId='3'
) 
WHERE institutions.id = (
  SELECT institudeId FROM review WHERE reviewId='3'
)
```

Comment: it is better solution.